# Effect modification on the absolute scale

Tags: causality, treatment-effect

Usually when talking about effect (measure) modification or treatment effect heterogeneity, we are talking about heterogeneity in the relative effect under two interventions in some subset of the population. For example, perhaps an intervention `A` is not more effective than intervention `B` in the population on average using some measure, but it is more effective in patients with a mutation that is targeted selectively by `A`. So this mutation would be an effect modifier of the treatment effect.

Does the concept equally apply to the effect of an intervention by itself? For example, patients with the mutation may benefit more from intervention `A` than other patients in the population. So in comparing the outcomes in patients who receive `A`, those with the mutation have better outcomes on average than the rest, but it may be the case that the mutation itself is not prognostic for the outcome independent of `A`. In this context, would we still be talking about effect modification by this mutation?